# macro with variadic arguments,

Tags: c++, macros, c++20

I get a macro like this:

```
#define REGIS(...) \
    extern "C" { \
    void libPort() \
    { \
        APPLY_TO_VARIADIC_ARGS(GENERATE_BUILDER, __VA_ARGS__) \
    }}

#define GENERATE_BUILDER(FOO, FUNC) \
    FOO::setFunc(FUNC); \
    FOO::register_<FOO>();

#define APPLY_TO_VARIADIC_ARGS(func, ...) \
    func(__VA_ARGS__)
```

when used like this:

```
class tes1 {
public:
    using fun_sig = std::function<void()>;
    static fun_sig m_func;
    static void setFunc(fun_sig f) { m_func = f; };
    template<typename T>
    static void register_() {};
};

REGIS(tes1, [](){ return; });
```

The following code will be generated:

```
extern "C" {
void libPort() {
    tes1::setFunc([]() { return; });
    tes1::register_<tes1>();
}}
```

Now I add another class:

```
class tes2 {
public:
    using fun_sig = std::function<int()>;
    static fun_sig m_func;
    static void setFunc(fun_sig f) { m_func = f; };
    template<typename T>
    static void register_() {};
};
```

and apply the generation like this:

```
REGIS(tes1, [](){ return; }, tes2 , [](){ return 1; });
```

I would expect to get the following generated:

```
void libPort() {
    tes1::setFunc([]() { return; });
    tes1::register_<tes1>();
    tes2::setFunc([]() { return 1; });
    tes2::register_<tes2>();
}
```

However, I get an error saying:

macro "GENERATE_BUILDER" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2..
My problem is probably that my macro is not correctly doing a recursive operation where each iteration selects the first two arguemtns.
I am using c++20.

Answer (score 0):

All arguments you pass to `REGIS` are being passed to `GENERATE_BUILDER`, so in the second case that is 4 arguments. But `GENERATE_BUILDER` only takes two arguments. There is no way with C-Macros to wrap each indiviual argument from a `__VA_ARGS__` list with another macro and especially no way to split them into a list of pairs. (At least no easy way.)

Beyond that, assuming that you want to have one single definition of the `libPort` function, you could do this: Register each class in a single step, i.e. have the `register_` function take the callback argument directly ...

```
class tes1 {
public:
    using fun_sig = std::function<void()>;
    static fun_sig m_func;
//  template<typename T> // <- This doesn't need to be a template if all you
                         //    ever pass for T is the class itself. 
    static void register_(fun_sig f) {
        m_func = std::move(f); // move here to avoid copying std::function
        // T is tes1, use it here if needed.
    }
};

class tes2 {
public:
    using fun_sig = std::function<int()>;
    static fun_sig m_func;
    static void register_(fun_sig f) {
        m_func = std::move(f);
        // T is tes2
    }
};
```

... and than write the `libPort` function manually like so:

```
extern "C" void libPort() {
    tes1::register_([]() { return; });
    tes2::register_([]() { return 1; });
}
```

Either way, with a macro or without, you have to maintain one line of code for each `tesN` class, so at least in your example the macro is not doing anything that would justify its existence.

Comment: yeah but that defies the whole idea for me to use macros to create boilerplate code :)

Comment: If writing `tesN::register_(...)` once per `tesN` class qualifies as boilerplate, than yes, there is hardly a way around that. If you really want to and your actual problem is of much larger scope than your example, you could have a look at how LLVM solves a similar problem with .def files: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def